# How to show overflow content in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, overflow, modal-dialog, trigger.io

I am using modals from bootstrap for my web/mobile application. And my intention was for my modals to fill up on the whole mobile screen when they are triggered. I have a added a custom css to make my modals 'full size'.

```
.modal {
  &.full_size {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

However, on the mobile phone, although I did successfully see a full screen modal being display, I don't seem to be able to see the contents that 'overflow' from the full screen modal i.e. if the content height is greater than my screen height, I won't be able to scroll down to see the rest of my content.

How can I resolve this so that I can scroll and see all my content in my modal?

Comment: try adding `overflow: auto;`

Comment: hi @koala_dev, yeap that did the work. Can you add your comment as an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks for your help on this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `overflow:auto;` to allow scrolling when the content exceeds the container's dimensions